# Create new role in WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 using APIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a project that require to work with WSO2 APIM only through his APIs without using any WSO2 UI ,i found the collection of API for Admin,publisher and Devportal from this link

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/reference/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v3/publisher-v3/#section/Authentication

but i can't found the APIs of Carbon Portal (so i can create role or user from APIs) .
I found this old documentation

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+User+Roles

but it didn't work for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [WSO2 Admin services](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/wso2-admin-services/) for this. These are SOAP Services.
Then use the `https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl` service.